# Class not found after requiring file containing use statement

Tags: php, redbean

I'm trying to use a file to setup a database connection with RedBeanPHP that can be included everywhere else. Example:

file1.php

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use RedBean_Facade as R;
R::setup();
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
require_once 'file1.php';
R::debug(true);
?>
```

However navigating to file2.php shows this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'R' not found in /file1.php on line 5

Do namespace use statements in PHP not get `include`d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP `namespace` and `use` declarations are only valid in the physical file they appear in. These declarations do not span across `require`s. They are already handled at compile-time.

If `a.php` uses aliases in its namespace, and it is included by `b.php`, the aliases defined in `a.php` will not be seen by `b.php`.

You will have to insert your `use` statement into every file. [Here's the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> Importing rules are per file basis

However, you can work around this using [class_alias](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php):

```
class_alias('RedBean_Facade', 'R');
```